# How to Resize column filter plugin controls for jquery datatable

Tags: datatables

how can i resize column filter plugin controls for jquery datatable.

I used below code for column filter plugin but it didnt changed...

```
 $("table#tblOscarNominees").dataTable().columnFilter(
            {
                //sPlaceHolder: "foot:before",
                "aoColumns": [
                                null, //{ "type": "number-range" },
                                {"type": "text", width: "50px" },
                                { "type": "select" },
                                { "type": "text", width: "50px" },
                                {"type": "number-range", width: "50px" },
                                { "type": "select" },
                                { "type": "select" },
                                { "type": "date-range", width: "50px" },
                                ]
            });
```

[image]

for more details please see this link

http://www.reddyinfosoft.blogspot.in/2012/12/jquery-datatable-plugin-in-aspnet-using.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$('#my-table th').bind('mouseup', function(event){
  var index = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
  var colWidth = $(this).css('width');
  var input = $('#my-table tfoot tr input:eq(' + index +')');
  input.css("width", colWidth);
});
```

You still need to set the input width right after the table is built:

```
$('#change-table tfoot tr').find(':input').each(function(index){
  var colWidth = $('#my-table thead tr th:eq(' + index + ')').css('width');
  $(this).css("width", colWidth );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two other things you can do:
include this in css or style section:

`.date_range_filter {
       width:3em;
}`

Also, you can set sRangeFormat inside columnFilter

`.columnFilter({
    sRangeFormat: "From {from}<br> to {to}" 
})`

(Or whatever code you want there.  The `{from}` and `{to}` get replaced with the input field.  Also note that trying to use table code in sRangeFormat didn't work for me - that seems like a code bug in columnFilter.)

Good luck!